# Are KeepAlive connections supported on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, streaming, keep-alive

I was trying to use an open (streaming) connection on the phone, using Hammock library. The problem is that Windows Phone doesn't seem to accept KeepAlive connections (`WebRequest.KeepAlive` is not available), and I would like to know if there's any way to use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible :

```
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(@"http://www.mysite.com", UriKind.Absolute)) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Headers["Connection"] = "Keep-Alive";
```